# How to get the path after tree subfolders via batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want a simple solution to get the right path with  the most recent folder for example 
 I have under
dir c:\folderx\foldery\folderz

Tools 1.0
  Tools 2.1
   Tools 3.1

I want to get the the last one 
exemple :
set Mytools_path="c:\folderx\foldery\folderz\tools 3.1"

Comment: Surely the most recent created date would determine the 'last one' instead of relying on alphabetical directory naming.

Comment: Ok thx how to sort by date?

Comment: I'd suggest a [powershell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394766/6738015).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ("c:\folderx\foldery\folderz \Tools 1.0 \Tools 2.1 \Tools 3.1") do set "mytools_path=%%~nxa"
```

Although the string is a pathname, using the above technique, it has the same structure as a filename, so the ~-operators of the `find/f` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The improper formatting of your question was misleading.

If no spaces in path:

```
for /d %%A in (c:\folderx\foldery\folderz\*) Do Set Set Mytools_path="%%A"
```

Otherwise:

```
Set Base=c:\folderx\foldery\folderz\
For /f "delims=" %%A in('Dir /B/AD "%Base%"') Do set Mytools_path="%Base%%%A"
```